# Поиск циклических ключей

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица некоторых сущностей, вложенных друг в друга таким образом, что `parent_id` одной сущности указывает на `id` другой из этой же таблицы:

```
 entity
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ name    ║ parent_id ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 0  ║ "Root"  ║ 0         ║ 
║ 1  ║ "One"   ║ 0         ║
║ 2  ║ "Two"   ║ 1         ║
║ 3  ║ "Three" ║ 4         ║
║ 4  ║ "Four"  ║ 3         ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Эти сущности можно редактировать(или создавать) через rest. В общем случае запросы простые и сводятся к следующим:
`insert into entity (name, parent_id) values (${name}, ${parentId});`
или
`update entity set (name = ${name}, parent_id = ${parentId}) where id = ${id};`

Так как в `parentId` можно подставить любое число. то чисто теоретически возможна ситуация как в приведенном примере:третья сущность ссылается на четвертую, а четвертая на третью. Таким образом мы получаем циклическую вложенность и построить валидное дерево из таких сущностей уже не возможно.

Думаю, что можно при добавлении сущностей проверять `parent_id` на циклические зависимости, но не знаю как это сделать средствами `Postgres`. Может кто-то уже решал такую задачу у себя?

---

**UPD** Идеи из комментария @vp_arth:

После добавления или "перемещения" под другого родителя, можно взять дерево всех родителей этой сущности:

```
  with recursive r as(
      select *
      from entity
      where id = $id
    union
       select et.*
       from entity as et
       join r
         on et.parent_id = r.id
   )
  select * from r
```

и поискать там данную сущность `where id = ${entityId}`.

Проблема в том, что в таком виде этот запрос "вешается", если есть циклическая вложенность. (Что в общем то ожидаемо)

Comment: Я решаю Вашу проблему соблюдением двух правил: при добавлении (insert) нового узла в дерева всегда указывать Id родителя, допуская null для корневых узлов; запрет в update менять ParentId. Техническая реализация зависит от конкретного окружения. При соблюдении этих правил у меня никогда не было проблем.

Comment: А если разрешать перемещение узла в другого родителя, то вопрос должен звучать так: "Не является ли новый родитель потомком данного узла?". В реализациях вроде NestedSets это элементарный вопрос. С простым parent_id необходим рекурсивный спуск.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов при добавлении сущностей тоже можно указать "неправильный" `parentId`, ведь ничто не ограничивает указать любой. Думаю, в Вашем случае проблема не решена, а просто не проявилась.

Comment: @vp_arth Обновил вопрос на основе Вашего комментария. Думаю мы на шажок стали ближе =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое, что можно предпринять - это установить ограничение:

```sql
alter table entity
    add constraint entity_pkey primary key (id),
    add constraint entity_parent_id_fkey foreign key (parent_id)
        references entity (id) match simple
        on update cascade on delete restrict;
```

Это позволит избежать ситуации с добавлением некорректной записи, когда у записи с `id=3` установлен `parent_id=4`, в то время когда записи с `id=4` ещё не существовало.
Кроме того, это может помочь вам обеспечить целостность БД, ведь если какая-то запись будет удалена, то дерево тоже нельзя будет построить.

Однако, это не спасёт вас от установки некорректных значений в процессе обновления записей.

Здесь я бы предложил вам использовать функцию (или хранимую процедуру), в которой можно пройтись по цепочке `parent_id` и предупредить некорректное обновление:

```sql
create or replace function update_entity(arg_id int, arg_name varchar, arg_parent_id int)
  returns table(id int, name varchar, parent_id int) as
$body$
declare
    parent_ids int[] = array(
        with recursive w_entity as (
            select
                e.id,
                e.parent_id
            from entity e
            where e.id = arg_id

            union

            select
                c.id,
                c.parent_id
            from entity c
            join w_entity p on
                c.parent_id = p.id
        )
        select e.id
        from w_entity e
        where e.parent_id is not null
    );
begin
    if arg_parent_id = any(parent_ids) then
        raise exception 'Некорректный parent_id: %', arg_parent_id;
    end if;

    return query
    update entity as e set
        name = arg_name,
        parent_id = arg_parent_id
    where e.id = arg_id
    returning *;
end;
$body$
  language plpgsql volatile;
```

Удобство этого варианта в том, что всё будет выполнено в одной транзакции, кроме того, вызов функций всегда удобней и короче:

```sql
select * from update_entity(1, 'some name', 3)
```

Кстати, описанная функция возвращает изменённую запись, так что если не требуется, уберите `returning *`. Если же посчитаете это удобным, то следите за тем, чтобы описание `returns table(id int, name varchar, parent_id int)` соответствовало количеству и типу столбцов в таблице `entity`, если измените столбцы, не изменив описание функции, - получите ошибку.

Минусы такого подхода в том, что он усложняет миграцию. Если вам потребуется перенести всё на другую СУБД, то переписывать функции - это дополнительная работа.

Попробуйте. Возможно, это вам поможет.

Удачи!